# Agregar mensaje a middleware laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un middleware que valida si la persona verificó su email, el cual funciona perfecto ya que si no lo verificó, lo devuelve al home.

¿cómo puedo agregar un mensaje de alerta una vez sea redirigido que diga que debe verificar su email, se puede con session flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, esa es la forma "correcta" de hacerlo según Laravel:

En el middleware:

```
$request->session()->flash('mensaje', 'Debes verificar tu correo');

return redirect('/home');
```

En el controlador que recibe la redirección:

```
$mensaje = $request->session()->has('mensaje') ? $request->session()->get('mensaje') : '';
```